# Parse push notification sent to 0 recipients

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

I am trying to make my app send push notifications to individual users (the users have been registered previously). The purpose of what I am trying to do is to inform the user that the order they have previously made on my store has been shipped.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *loggedUser = [userDefaults stringForKey:@"loggedUser"];

PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[installation addUniqueObject:loggedUser forKey:@"channels"];
[installation saveInBackground];
```

(I did not use `PFUser` and instead there is the variable `loggedUser` that works perfectly fine.)

The code above seem to work fine, because if I go to the Data Browser on Parse, I can see the username on the installation table, channel column.

However, although I see the user on the cloud code, which means it has been successfully uploaded when I send the Push Notification, I see that it was sent to 0 recipients.

The push is being sent through JavaScript, using the following code:

(The variable `user` is stated above and I have made sure it also works fine.)

```
Parse.Push.send({
    channels: "[\""+user+"\"]",
    data: {
        alert: "Your order has been shipped."
    }
}, {
    success: function() {
        alert('The push notification has been sent correctly')
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert('Error: '+ error)
    }
});
```

Does someone know what am I doing wrong? Is it that `channels:` is incorrectly written? Or is it because I can't use a variable inside this Parse send action?

**EDIT:**

This is the whole document

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Parse.$ = jQuery;
Parse.initialize("APPLICATION ID", "JAVASCRIPT KEY");

var PhotoObject = Parse.Object.extend("PhotoObject");
var query = new Parse.Query(PhotoObject);
query.equalTo("allowed", false);
query.equalTo("appear", true);
query.descending("createdAt");
query.find({

    success: function(results) {

        // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
        var object = results[i];
        var profilePhoto = object.get("image");
        var description = object.get("description");
        var location = object.get("location");
        var user = object.get("user");
        var copyLocation = '';
        var copyDescription = '';
        var copyUser = '';

        if (description === '') {
            copyDescription = '<em>No description.</em>';
        }else {
            copyDescription = description;
        }

        if (location === '') {
            copyDescription = '<em>Could not determine location.</em>';
        }else {
            copyLocation = location;
        }

        if (user === undefined ) {
            copyUser = '<em>Could not determine user.</em>';
        }else {
            copyUser = user;
        }

        $('#images').append("<li class='listItem"+i+"' id='"+object.id+"listItem''><img class='liPhoto' id='imagesID"+i+"' src='"+profilePhoto.url()+"'/></li>");
        $("#imagesID"+i).wrap("<a href='"+profilePhoto.url()+"'/>");

        $(".listItem"+i).append("<p class='description'><strong>Description: </strong>"+copyDescription+"<br><br><strong>User: </strong>"+copyUser+"<br><br><strong>Location: </strong>"+copyLocation+"</p>");

        $(".listItem"+i).append("<br><br><button class='selectionButton' id='"+object.id+"'>Accept</button><button class='selectionButton'id='"+object.id+"decline'>Decline</button>");

        }

        $("button").click(function() {

            if ((this.id).indexOf("decline") <= 0){

                console.log('approve button pressed');
                var query = new Parse.Query(PhotoObject);
                query.get(this.id, {


                    success: function(photoObject) {

                        // The object was retrieved successfully.
                        photoObject.set("allowed", true);

                        photoObject.save(null, {

                            success: function(photoObject) {

                                // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
                                var idName = '#'+photoObject.id+'listItem';
                                console.log(idName);
                                $(idName).slideUp();

                                alert('The image was approved succesfully - '+ photoObject.id);

                                Parse.Push.send({
                                    channels: [user],

                                    data: {
                                        alert: "Your image has been successfully moderated and has been published on the gallery!"
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    success: function() {
                                        alert('The push notification has been sent correctly')
                                    },

                                    error: function(error) {
                                        console.log(error);
                                        alert('Error: '+ error)
                                    }
                                });
                            },


                            error: function(photoObject, error) {
                                // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
                                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                                        alert('Failed to approve the image, with error code: ' + error.description);
                            }

                        });

                    },

                    error: function(object, error) {
                        // The object was not retrieved successfully.
                        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                    }

                });

            } else {
                console.log('decline button pressed');
                var query = new Parse.Query(PhotoObject);
                var idFormated = this.id.replace('decline','');
                console.log(idFormated);

                query.get(idFormated, {

                    success: function(photoObject) {
                        // The object was retrieved successfully.
                        photoObject.set("appear", false);

                        photoObject.save(null, {

                            success: function(photoObject) {
                                // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
                                var idName = '#'+photoObject.id+'listItem';
                                console.log(idName);
                                $(idName).slideUp();

                                alert('The image was declined succesfully - '+ photoObject.id);
                            },

                            error: function(photoObject, error) {
                                // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
                                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                                alert('Failed to declined the image, with error code: ' + error.description);
                            }
                        });

                    },

                    error: function(object, error) {
                        // The object was not retrieved successfully.
                        alert('Failed to declined the image, with error code: ' + error.description);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    },

    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not specifying the object I wanted to change. 
Instead of:

```
object.get('user');
```

It was:

```
photoObject.get('user');
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is change the way you're sending channels in `Parse.Push.send()`

```
channels: [user],
```

Assuming `user` is a string that matches `loggedUser` from the previous code.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. I got ``Error: [object Object]`` as an error alert.

Comment: Don't log 'Error: ', just pass `error` to console.log, then we'll see the real error.  `console.log(error);`

Comment: This is the error I got: ``Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)``

Comment: Where is this running? Is Parse initialized?

Comment: Sorry, it seemed that if I clicked on the error on the console, more information opened up. Here is an [image](http://i.imgur.com/KAnaZpH.png). PD: Yes, Parse has been initialized.

Comment: how about `console.log(user);`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If I log ``user`` I get this error ``ReferenceError: Can't find variable: user``

Comment: so then what did you expect to be in user and where did it come from?.. if you called this in a cloud function, maybe you meant request.user.

Comment: Well, there is a table in Cloud Code from Parse that it is getting all the information from. It is a moderation page that moderates images so that they are shown on the app after being accepted. This document is querying from a table all rows that have ``allowed`` set to ``FALSE``. I included the ``var user = object.get("user");`` after initializing Parse. Up to this point it is working correctly because I can successfully print ``user`` and it works. [...]

Comment: [...] Once the moderator clicks on 'Accept' to add the image to the gallery, this function does two things: 1, changes the ``allowed`` column to ``TRUE``. 2, sends the push notification using the code above. (I know this is hard to understand but I hope you get the main idea.)

Comment: you'll need to add more code.  the whole cloud function should do it.

Comment: ``user = object.get("user");``. It is not directly a string, but a pointer to ``user`` at Parse.com. The fact is that the variable ``user`` is effectively working for displaying images that need to be moderated. In the moderation page, just beneath each image, the user is stated.. and works. I think the whole problem must come from the variable ``user`` not being publicly shared between methods.

Comment: this is why you need to post the -entire- function.

Comment: Yes, probably a scope issue.  define user outside, at the top, `var user = false;`.. drop the `var` from where you set `user`.

Comment: I did not understand that last part, how do I fix it? :S

Comment: define user at the top of your script, so it's global.  then don't use `var user` again (just use `user = result.get('user');`)..  elsewhere, `user` should be accessible.

Comment: I worked it out, apparently I needed to specify the table I wanted to get the user from. Thank you very much for your patience :)